# Incorporate C library function into Perl6 with NativeCall

Tags: raku, nativecall

I am attempting to use `lgamma` from C's `math.h` in Perl6.

How can I incorporate this into Perl6?

I have tried

```
use NativeCall;

sub lgamma(num64 --> num64) is native(Str) {};

say lgamma(3e0);

my $x = 3.14;
say lgamma($x);
```

This works for the first number (a `Str`) but fails for the second, `$x`, giving the error:

```
This type cannot unbox to a native number: P6opaque, Rat
  in block <unit> at pvalue.p6 line 8
```

I want to do this very simply, like in Perl5: `use POSIX 'lgamma';` and then `lgamma($x)` but I don't see how to do that in Perl6.

Comment: Can you please post the whole error?

Comment: @jjmerelo I've updated the post to more completely show the error

Comment: Try using the `num64` native type when declaring `$x`: `my num64 $x = 3.14.Num`. It also seems to work without the `num64` declarator: `my $x = 3.14.Num`

Comment: You can also use `3.14e0` to create a `Num` literal

Comment: I imagine `is native(Str)` doesn't do what you think it does. (It doesn't do what I think it does either, because I don't have any thoughts about what it does other than that it makes no sense to me. :)) I suspect it turns into the equivalent of `is native('')` which I imagine in turn is the same as `is native`. For more info, see [the `is native` doc](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall#Library_paths_and_names). Similarly "This works for the first number (a `Str`)" isn't right because the first number (`3e0`) is not a string / `Str` but instead a `Num`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The errors with native values isn't always clear.

Basically it is saying that a Rat isn't a Num.

`3.14` is a Rat. (Rational)

```perl6
say 3.14.^name; # Rat
say 3.14.nude.join('/'); # 157/50
```

---

You could just always coerce the value to Num everytime you call it.

```perl6
lgamma( $x.Num )
```

That doesn't seem so great.

---

I would just wrap the native sub in another one that coerces all Real numbers to Num.
(Real is all Numeric except Complex)

```perl6
sub lgamma ( Num(Real) \n --> Num ){
  use NativeCall;
  sub lgamma (num64 --> num64) is native {}

  lgamma( n )
}

say lgamma(3);    # 0.6931471805599453
say lgamma(3.14); # 0.8261387047770286
```

Comment: what does the "\n" mean? I've seen that before, but can't find what it means

Comment: @con It is how you declare a “variable” without a sigil (`$@%`). In a signature it is a bit like declaring it as `raw` `:( \n )` `:( $n is raw )`. I mainly used it here because the code is short and it doesn't need the protections that declaring it with `$` would have provided.

Answer (score 5):

Your `$x` has no type. If you use any type for it, say `num64`, it will say:

```
Cannot assign a literal of type Rat (3.14) to a native variable of type num. You can declare the variable to be of type Real, or try to coerce the value with 3.14.Num or Num(3.14)
```

So you do exactly that:

```
my  num64 $x = 3.14.Num;
```

This converts the number exactly to the representation that is required by `lgamma`